# How to keep torch on when user presses Home button

Tags: ios

I am writing a Flashlight app. I use the following code to switch the flashlight on:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (device.hasTorch)
{
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

But when the user presses Home button or Sleep button, the light goes off. How can I prevent it? I am asking because standard iOS flashlight (from Control Center) keeps lighting permanently even if I press Home or Sleep buttons.

Comment: You can't. Apple can do more than we can with our apps.

Comment: Weeeell, the control center is made by apple, most of the apple apps can do more than regular apps are allowed to.